# Read data from binary file into matlab, split into vector

Tags: matlab, file, binary, octave

I need help reading in data from a binary file into an array of 100000x16 dimensions. I'm using octave.

Here's the link to screenshot of how the file looks: http://s29.postimg.org/uclh7whtz/Screenshot.png

I've tried using fscanf and fread but don't know what way to go with them- using them messed up with the precision, and so on...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `"dlmread"` function in MATLAB in the following way.

```
a=dlmread('file.dat','\t',1,0);
```

This will skip the header row and reads complete numeric matrix. Here is an example:

```
file name=example.dat

time    x1  y1  z1
0.000   0.084   0.015   0.0181
0.016   0.008   0.001   0.8012
0.032   0.081   0.064   0.235

a=dlmread('example.dat','\t',1,0);

a =

         0    0.0840    0.0150    0.0181
    0.0160    0.0080    0.0010    0.8012
    0.0320    0.0810    0.0640    0.2350
```

Please go through the `dlmread` help for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If it messed up with the precision, there is a good chance you just need to specify the values of the 16 rows as floats `%f` as in:

```
 fid=fopen(strcat(Name,'.dat'));
 C=textscan(fid, '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f'); % one '%f' for row, is that 16?
 fclose(fid);
```

This will of course ignore the headers (but I guess you wanted to do that any way, didn't you?).